# Switch to FastCGI from Apache php support disabled mod_deflate

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, fastcgi, mod-deflate

After i was told by my server providers support staff to swtich to FastCGI from Apache php support, i later found out that `mod_deflate` stopped working, it was working fine before the switch. My static files were delivered without being gzipped. I did a grep via ssh for `mod_deflate` in my `httpd.conf` and the module wasn't commented out.

I was advised to make the switch because of permission errors on my WordPress install. All my plugins were creating files/folders that were owned by `apache`. I'm not sure if this was the proper course of action, it definitely solved the permission problems, and all files/folders which are created now are owned by my ftp user.

I'd rather stick to what I've got configured on my vps instead of moving to things such as `php-fpm`, any suggestions on how to resolve this problem internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem. The problem was that `AddOutputFilterByType` was wrapped around `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` in my `.htaccess` file, which worked when i was using Apache php support.

I'm really not sure how these modules are loaded on specific circumstances. Perhaps someone can explain to me what just happened through the comments? Thanks!